# How to set view's layout column in code (view is inside tablerow)?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a tablelayout in xml. I am also adding some rows to it in code. How can i set some view's column_layout in code?

In xml i have:

```
android:layout_column="3"
```

How to achieve the same in code (e.g. for TextView)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        TextView tv = new TextView(this); 
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the questions, however MyTracks for Android provides some nice example code using a table layout. It can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/res/layout/about.xml?name=v1.0.17).

Thanks for the comment. I think this is what you are looking for:
< TableLayout xmlns:
    android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="3">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Open..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-O"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="String"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow> ...`
```

Comment: I need to put textview to column 3 inside tablerow in code. In xml, this is done with "android:layout_column" attribute.

Comment: I need to do the same thing that you posted in java code (not xml), sorry for my badly formed question.